# googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE); doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps

i have this code working good and the map is displayed right

```
package com.jameselsey.mapme;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MapMe extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        GoogleMap googleMap =fragment.getMap();

    }
}
```

but when i try to add this line

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

the application stop running with exception

Comment: What's the exception? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: sorry the application is working only on my tablet it's not working on the emulator

Comment: No, the stacktrace/logcat.

Comment: i get this exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jameselsey.mapme/com.jameselsey.mapme.MapMe}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: so because of that exception i can't run it on the emulator

Comment: by the way i'm sure now that the return object from GoogleMap googleMap =fragment.getMap(); is null but i don't know way

Comment: thanks a lot it's solved by using this code final MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment() { @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); map = getMap(); map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN); map.setIndoorEnabled(true);

Comment: @ahmadswaid,..Note that the new Google Maps API version 2 does not work in the emulator. It works just only on the real device(handset or Tablet). Please see [the official document, click here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/google/play-services/setup.html)